# Convert jQuery .click into .live 'click' in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, click

This works:

```
$('#products.table tr').click ->
  $(@).toggleClass('row_selected')
```

This doesn't:

```
$('#products.table tr').live 'click', (event) ->
  $(@).toggleClass('row_selected')
```

Error in browser's console:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#products.table tr').live')
    ready (products.js, line 10)
    fire (jquery.js, line 3049)
    fireWith (jquery.js, line 3161)
    ready (jquery.js, line 434)
    completed (jquery.js, line 105)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated as of jQuery version 1.7, and Rails 3's default jQuery version is 1.9.  You need to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

Try:

```
$(document).on 'click', '#products.table tr', (event) ->
  if ( $(@).hasClass('row_selected') )
    $(@).removeClass('row_selected')
  else
    $(@).addClass('row_selected')
```

or, you could use the `toggleClass` method as suggested in the comments as:

```
$(document).on 'click', '#products.table tr', (event) ->
  $(@).toggleClass('row_selected')
```

Comment: Might as well switch to [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) while you're there: `$(@).toggleClass('row_selected')`.

Comment: This wouldn't work: `$('#products.table tr').on 'click', (event) ->` but what you have now starting with `$(document).on…` works great! Would love an explanation from someone as to why if/when they get a chance...